# Discrete Laplace operator and its eigenvalues

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

I wonder is there any geometric interpretation of the eigenvalues ​​of the discrete Laplace operator on graphs? Maybe there is a relationship between the eigenvalues ​​and combinatorial properties of the graph?

I would like to know what information eigenvalues contain.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The magic words are "spectral graph theory". Google it.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend the following book as for reference:

Chung, Fan R. K. Spectral graph theory. CBMS Regional Conference Series in Mathematics, 92. Published for the Conference Board of the Mathematical Sciences, Washington, DC; by the American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1997.

I was learning basic notion and analysis on graphs as well. This book contains almost every topics related to analysis.

Comment: Problem is, Chung's book is solely devoted to the so-called normalized Laplacian, whose spectral properties have very little in common with those of the discrete Laplacian. Mohar's survey are probably a better start.